# I can't load the images in the .jar file (Spring)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**Locally, everything works well for me.** 
When I build a project and **run it on the server** it will not load images.
*How do I change it to load as getInputStream, or some other way to work in a .jar file?*
I use this code:

```
private final Path root = Paths.get("images");
@Override
  public Resource load(String filename){
    try{
        Path file = root.resolve(filename);
        Resource resource = new UrlResource(file.toUri());
      if (resource.exists() || resource.isReadable()) {
        return resource;
      } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not read the file!");
      }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

I tried to use from this link, **but it won't show me the image after BufferedReader:**
https://www.baeldung.com/java-classpath-resource-cannot-be-opened

Comment: are you using docker? can you share the error?

Comment: @deadshot I use Spring and React on VPS

Comment: are you getting the error if you run the jar locally?

Comment: @deadshot I don't get an error when I run jar locally

Comment: is `filename` absolute path or just a name?

Comment: @deadshot just a name

Comment: check if you getting the error for other files?

Comment: Do it  spring like: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-classpath-file-access  Generally all files inside the resource folder in your jar can be access by `Class#getResourceAsStream`.

Comment: @deadshot It works locally for me, when I run the application on the server I get: java.io.FileNotFoundException: URL [file:/root/C:/Desktop/careermdhub/images/ligue1.jpg]. So can I change the path somehow?

Comment: It's not looking in the classpath try using `ClassPathResource`

Comment: Thank you for your help, I succeeded with the help of ResourceLoader